# How to save the response from a HTTP call until successs in Mule?

Tags: mule, mule-component

We are trying to call a REST service with a Mule HTTP connector. If we dont get a success, we want to re-send the request, something like this:
`<until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore"
                      failureExpression="#[header:INBOUND:http.status != 200]"
                      maxRetries="6"
                      secondsBetweenRetries="600">
<http:request config-ref="ComAroundREST_API" path="api/v1/mostread" method="GET" doc:name="GetMostReadRESTCall">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="Take" value="5"/>
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
</until-successful`

However, we need the successfull response if we get one such. Is there a way to retrieve it and set it in the payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to process it synchronously. Check out the Synchronous Until-Successful section [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope)

Comment: Thanks, exactly the case.